# asset() returning wrong URL in Symfony Twig template

Tags: symfony, stylesheet

I'm learning the Symfony framework and I'm having problems getting it to return the correct URL to a resource. I created a new bundle, Company/TestBundle, with this in my src/Company/TestBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php file:

```
<?php

namespace Company\TestBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('TestBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

In src/Company/TestBundle/Resources/views/Default/index.html.twig:

```
{% extends "SmallworldBundle:Default:main.html.twig" %}

{%block title %}It's a small world after all!{% endblock %}

{% block body %} It's a small world! {% endblock %}
```

And in src/Company/TestBundle/Resources/views/Default/main.html.twig:

```
<html>
<head>
{% block stylesheets %}
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "{{ asset('css/small.css') }}" type = "text/css" />
{% endblock %}
<title>{% block title %} {% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
{%block body %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Now, I've run php app/console assets:install --symlink but even so, the generated code is trying to link to '/css/small.css' instead of where the file actually is, which is src/Company/TestBundle/Resources/public/css/small.css

Can someone explain why this isn't linking to the correct location?

Answer (score 1):

Though NoScope's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16729516/1832745) is a valid solution you are better off not introducing a hard dependency to web/bundles/testbundle.

You should use ...

```
{% block stylesheets '@CompanyTestBundle/Resources/public/css/small.css' %}
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" type = "text/css" />
{% endblock %}
```

... instead.

This way if you change the way assetic installs your assets you will still have the correct path displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the bundle name as well like:

{{ asset('bundles/testbundle/css/small.css') }}